# Woocommerce product search not checking "product_tag"?

Tags: wordpress, search, tags, product, woocommerce

It appears as tho the search functionality for WooCommerce products does not check "product_tag" taxonomy terms, nor SKU field?  I added the SKUs as product tags to their respective products, but it still returns nothing when I search for the SKU.... How do I make the search functionality check product_tag terms? I have tried many many many things from adding tax_query to pre_get_post filter, to a whole new WP_Query loop, it just fails to search product_tags for some reason....so what is the point in a Product Tag???

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the code from woo and others to search SKU with no results. However, the plugin search-everything, download from repository, does the job.

Answer (score 0):

> **I got the solution to search the products by SKU code.**

It is too simple just paste the following code in function.php and then you can see the changes in search results.

```
function search_by_id_only( $search, &$query_vars ) {
    global $wpdb, $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' == $pagenow || empty($search) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_sku',
                'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if ( empty( $posts ) ) return $search;
    $get_post_ids = array();
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
    }
    if ( sizeof( $get_post_ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $get_post_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_id_only', 999, 2 );
```