# Enable custom taxonomies in WooCommerce product search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

**What I want:** modify the query of the WooCommerce search form (in frontend) to display the products by searching in the name, description and product_tag of the products.

**What I have:** I'm trying with this code [inspired from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985363/woocommerce-product-search-not-checking-product-tag/56985529#56985529) that return a result for the name and description of the product. But if i make a search with the tags names, no results. The search query don't search in tags of the product.

How to reproduce this issue *(put the code below in functions.php file of your active theme)*:

```
function search_product_by_tag( $search, &$query_vars ) {
    global $wpdb, $pagenow;

    if ( 'edit.php' == $pagenow || empty($search) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
       'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'taxonomy',
                'value' => 'product_tag',
                'field' => 'name',
                'terms' => array($query_vars->query['s']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )));
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    if ( empty( $posts ) ) return $search;
    $get_post_ids = array();
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
    }
    if ( sizeof( $get_post_ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $get_post_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_product_by_tag', 999, 2 );
```

**Example:** I've one product : Black Chocolate with the product tag "confection". With this code, if i search "Chocolate" in the search form, the product will be returned. But if i search "confection" : no results.
[image: Frontend search result]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes and errors in your code *(a tax query is required for example)*.

To include **WooCommmerce product tag terms in WooCommerce product search only** *(front end)* use the following:

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended', 999, 2 );
function woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended( $search, $query ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp;

    $qvars = $wp->query_vars;

    if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s'])
    && isset($qvars['post_type']) && ! empty($qvars['s'])
    && $qvars['post_type'] === 'product' ) ) {
        return $search;
    }
    
    // Here set your custom taxonomy
    $taxonomy = 'product_tag'; // WooCommerce product tag

    // Get the product Ids
    $ids = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'fields'          => 'ids',
        'tax_query'       => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => esc_attr($qvars['s']),
        )),
    ));

    if ( count( $ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **To make it work On WordPress search too** replace:
>
> ```
>     if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s'])
>     && isset($qvars['post_type']) && ! empty($qvars['s'])
>     && $qvars['post_type'] === 'product' ) ) {
> ```
>
> By the following:
>
> ```
>     if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s']) && ! empty($qvars['s']) ) ) {
> ```

---

For WooCommerce **product category** you will replace:

```
$taxonomy = 'product_tag'; // WooCommerce product tag
```

with:

```
$taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // WooCommerce product category
```

---

For WooCommerce **product brands** you will replace:

```
$taxonomy = 'product_tag'; // WooCommerce product tag
```

with:

```
$taxonomy = 'product_brand'; // WooCommerce product Brands
```

---

#### For multiple taxonomies.

To enable the search for **both** product category terms and product tag terms, you will use:

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended', 999, 2 );
function woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended( $search, $query ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp;

    $qvars = $wp->query_vars;

    if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s'])
    && isset($qvars['post_type']) && ! empty($qvars['s'])
    && $qvars['post_type'] === 'product' ) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    // Here set your custom taxonomies in the array
    $taxonomies = array('product_tag', 'product_cat');

    $tax_query  = array('relation' => 'OR'); // Initializing tax query

    // Loop through taxonomies to set the tax query
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => esc_attr($qvars['s']),
        );
    }

    // Get the product Ids
    $ids = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'fields'          => 'ids',
        'tax_query'       => $tax_query,
    ) );

    if ( sizeof( $ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **To make it work On WordPress search too** replace:
>
> ```
>     if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s'])
>     && isset($qvars['post_type']) && ! empty($qvars['s'])
>     && $qvars['post_type'] === 'product' ) ) {
> ```
>
> By the following:
>
> ```
>     if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s']) && ! empty($qvars['s']) ) ) {
> ```

**New Thread**: [Extend WooCommerce product search to custom taxonomies and custom fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541202/extend-woocommerce-product-search-to-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-fields/63541607#63541607)

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec and thanks for the reply. But i don't talk about the admin product filter, i wanna talk about the frontend (customer) search form query. I've update my question to include a screenshot of what i wanna talk.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I've put the first code in my function.php file but, as you can see, the query don't search in product_tag :
Product configuration : https://imgur.com/1m2rHwQ
Search result : https://imgur.com/wbkFhwK

Comment: That is incredible because, in your test server, i search "hat" and i have 2 results : 2 pages whose the description contain "what". https://www.cbleu.net/sites/woo/?s=hat
 **But no one product with the tag "hat"**. What about you ?
https://i.gyazo.com/795f10f89258e753d46c71411d441b01.png

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, I want to add product sku and product title and product short description in the search too, Please help

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, pardon me, I am new here and still learning StackOverflow features. I just upvote the answer :) 
Regarding the question, I have achieved product_tag and product_category search, and last I only want sku in search query. Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541202/modify-woocommerce-default-search-with-sku-and-product-tag-and-product-category