# Extend WooCommerce product search to custom taxonomies and custom fields

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I am creating advance woocommerce search and I want to add sku and product_tag and product_category in search query. Below I am using *[Enable custom taxonomies in WooCommerce product search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131123/enable-custom-taxonomies-in-woocommerce-product-search/63134264#63134264)* answer code, that enable search for multiple taxonomies:

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended', 999, 2 );
function woocommerce_search_product_tag_extended( $search, $query ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp;

    $qvars = $wp->query_vars;

    if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s'])
    && isset($qvars['post_type']) && ! empty($qvars['s'])
    && $qvars['post_type'] === 'product' ) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    // Here set your custom taxonomies in the array
    $taxonomies = array('product_tag', 'product_cat');

    $tax_query  = array('relation' => 'OR'); // Initializing tax query

    // Loop through taxonomies to set the tax query
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => esc_attr($qvars['s']),
        );
    }

    // Get the product Ids
    $ids = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'fields'          => 'ids',
        'tax_query'       => $tax_query,
    ) );

    if ( sizeof( $ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}
```

I want to add product sku too in search query, how to add it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following will extend Product search to multiple taxonomies (Product Category and Product tag) and multiple custom fields (as SKU here):

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'woocommerce_search_product_mega_extended', 999, 2 );
function woocommerce_search_product_mega_extended( $search, $query ) {
    global $wpdb, $wp;

    $qvars = $wp->query_vars;

    if ( is_admin() || empty($search) ||  ! ( isset($qvars['s'])
    && isset($qvars['post_type']) && ! empty($qvars['s'])
    && $qvars['post_type'] === 'product' ) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    // SETTINGS:
    $taxonomies = array('product_tag', 'product_cat'); // Here set your custom taxonomies in the array
    $meta_keys  = array('_sku'); // Here set your product meta key(s) in the array

    // Initializing tax query
    $tax_query  = count($taxonomies) > 1 ? array('relation' => 'OR') : array();

    // Loop through taxonomies to set the tax query
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => esc_attr($qvars['s']),
        );
    }

    // Get the product Ids from taxonomy(ies)
    $tax_query_ids = (array) get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'fields'          => 'ids',
        'tax_query'       => $tax_query,
    ) );

    // Initializing meta query
    $meta_query = count($meta_keys) > 1 ? array('relation' => 'OR') : array();

    // Loop through taxonomies to set the tax query
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'value'   => esc_attr($qvars['s']),
        );
    }

    // Get the product Ids from custom field(s)
    $meta_query_ids = (array) get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
        'fields'          => 'ids',
        'meta_query'      => $meta_query,
    ) );

    $product_ids = array_unique( array_merge( $tax_query_ids, $meta_query_ids ) ); // Merge Ids in one array  with unique Ids

    if ( sizeof( $product_ids ) > 0 ) {
        $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $product_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
    return $search;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Enable custom taxonomies in WooCommerce product search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131123/enable-custom-taxonomies-in-woocommerce-product-search/63134264#63134264)

Comment: Thanks alot sir :) it's perfectly working with latest wordpress and woocommerce version

Comment: For me it was working for some taxonomy terms and not others, so to get it to work, I had to modify the `$search =`  line at the bottom by moving one of the brackets. So it's now:

```$search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ( ({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $product_ids ) . ")) OR ((", $search); ```

Comment: Also, in the second foreach loop, you've hard-coded '_sku'. Instead that loop should be:


```// Loop through custom fields to set the meta query
foreach( $meta_keys as $meta_key ) {
  $meta_query[] = [
    'key'     => $meta_key,
    'value'   => esc_attr($qvars['s']),
  ];
}```

Comment: Works but you have to type the full name of the product tag, if you have tag with multiple words example called ONE TWO THREE and search for "ONE" then you get 0 results.